# Easy to use field-based, copywriting collaboration tool

Tags: text-editor, collaboration

I'm looking for a tool that would make easier for our team to manage planned newsletters, blog posts, facebook posts, etc.

It needs to be easy for use for non-tech savvy users.

It would be nice if it would have a "fields" functionality, so for example, we would have "Article" document type, with defined fields:

- Title - plain text
- Headline - plain text - max chars 80
- Image
- Text - Limited rich text editor with selected options
- Pull Quote - plain text

[image: example what I mean]
An image of from [CraftCMS](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/matrix-fields.html), however, Craft was made for an entirely different usage scenario.

Requirements:

- version control
- collaboration (comments, real-time editing)
- folders or/and tags organization
- no markdown
- desktop app or fast browser app

Nice to have:

- Shopify integration
- Klaviyo/Drip/MailChimp integrations

We tried Google Docs, but it ended too complicated and frustrating to use for most of the team.

Comment: What I found myself is [GatherContent](https://gathercontent.com/), however I'm open to hearing some other options.

Answer (score 1):

[Slite](http://slite.com) answers all these requirements and makes it super easy for teams to collaborate on this type of content + super easy to use for the entire team (versus Gdocs)